# SQL Server Merge Replication - Safely shrink transaction log

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I have a couple of SQL databases running in merge replication.  My publishers HDD is full due to the transaction log of the database being replicated which is causing my snapshot agent to fail (out of disk space).

I want to shrink my transaction logs.  If I do, will it break my replication?  If it will break my replication, is there a way I can tell my publisher to put its files on a different HDD without having to restart replication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can shrink the transaction log without it breaking replication.  You can also move the publisher files to a different HDD by using ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILE syntax, setting the publication database offline, copying the files to the new location, and bringing it back online.

I would start with shrinking the transaction log and see if that helps.